# Disable cache during development: Templates are not discovered

Tags: caching

I have followed all steps reported on https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914. However, if I create an new template file in my theme folder, it does not get discovered until I flush the cache manually via `drush cr`.

Is rebuilding the cache a must to discover new templates, or can I optimize the developer settings to auto-discover templates during development?

Comment: If you are  editing the files (which also means adding files) of a theme that is used from Drupal, then you need to manually clear the cache, or tell Drupal not to use any cache. I would rather uninstall the theme before any edits, and install it back after the edits.

Comment: Which of the disabling methods on https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914 did you follow?

Comment: I have followed all methods. Uninstalling and installing the theme back is a very slow process, just to see my changes. Than cannot be the workflow. What do I need to do, to be able to work on my templates without having the need to constantly rebuild the cache manually?

Answer (score 0):

try add this in .htaccess  (drupal root)

```
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
       //ADD THIS 
        Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Expires 0
    </IfModule>
```